# jQuery mobile loading page again on hitting back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have the following three HTML files

[snapshot http://maroonlemoon.com/egather/screen.png](http://maroonlemoon.com/egather/screen.png)

When user logs in on the index page, I use the following event to navigate to page Home.html

```
  $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change","home.html", {
                  transition: "slide",
                  reverse: false,
                  changeHash: true,
            });
```

Home.html page loads all page contents (the list view as shown in screenshot) using the event

```
$(document).one('pageinit',function(){  
     ShowHomePage(); //This function binds all page buttons and also 
                       retrieves the list through an AJAX call
});
```

The above event call as well as ShowHomePage are both found in a javascript file that is being invoked before the closing tag of the div data-role="page" of Home.html

```
<script src="js/page.js"></script>
```

When users tap on any list item, I navigate them to the external Activity.html page using the same event used in Index.html

```
$( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change","activity.html", {
                          transition: "slide",
                          reverse: false,
                          changeHash: true,
                          reload:false
                        });
```

The back arrow in Activity.html has the data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse" data-rel="back" attributes and triggers perfectly fine going back to Home.html, however the whole page gets reloaded again entirely and I just want it to return to the previous page state without reloading and rebinding everything. What's weird to me is that if I start the flow from Home.html instead of Index.html (I mean if I don't login and directly go to home.html), and hit a list item and go back again, the page works exactly how I want it to (not reloading again).

Any ideas how to overcome this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I left out the data-dom-cache="true" on

```
 <div data-role="page" id="homepage" data-dom-cache="true">
```

Comment: In _single page model_, external pages aren't kept in DOM except for first page load. Once you navigate away of a page, JQM removes it. So when you navigate back to the same page, it's _reload_ and all bindings are duplicated. http://jqmtricks.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/single-page.png

Comment: Yes I knew that @Omar I just forgot to enable caching. It's working fine now. Thanks for the flowchart btw :)